# How to remove previous array() function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Please check the follow pic:

[image]

How can I remove the array() function before the row rata?
What I want to get is the output of 'a'.

I've searched the answer but didn't find it.

Thank you!

Comment: model_coef_ is of type ndarray. You can convert it to a list, and "get rid of array" in print, as in `list(model.coef_)`

Comment: Removing `data-science` tag as it's irrelevant.

Comment: `[*model.coef_, model.intercept_]`? or `np.r_[model.coef_, model.intercept_]` to get numpy array as output or `np.hstack([model.coef_, model.intercept_])`.

Comment: The outpus of [*model.coef_, model.intercept_] is just what I wanna get. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a simple numpy array:

```
In [34]: x=np.array([1.2, 3.4])
```

Its `repr` display includes the `array` label, identifying its type:

```
In [35]: x
Out[35]: array([1.2, 3.4])
```

Its `str` display does not include it. But also note the missing comma.  That distinguishes it from a list display:

```
In [36]: print(x)
[1.2 3.4]
```

Your second example embeds the array in a list:

```
In [37]: y = [x, 3]
In [38]: y
Out[38]: [array([1.2, 3.4]), 3]
In [39]: print(y)
[array([1.2, 3.4]), 3]
```

Here the `str` vs `repr` distinction does not apply.

But if you first convert the array to a list:

```
In [40]: y = [x.tolist(), 3]
In [41]: y
Out[41]: [[1.2, 3.4], 3]
```

And from the comments, `unpacking` the array:

```
In [42]: y = [*x, 3]
In [43]: y
Out[43]: [1.2, 3.4, 3]
```

In Python each class has its own formatting methods, `str` usually is the shorter, `repr` the fuller.  Besides showing values they may give some idea of the object's identity.  You may not need that identity information in your display, but don't ignore it.

Try to squeeze in some basic Python and numpy reading; it will help in the long run.